# Can't $push a new array to document in Meteor Collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've been learning Meteor for about 3 weeks, and am still trying to wrap my head around updating/querying collections. I'm trying to build a Slack clone, and created the following collection with one set of fixture documents:

```
Conversations.insert({
    channel: "#defaultChannel",
    createdBy: "coffeemeup",
    timestamp: new Date(),
    followers: ["username1", "username2"],
    entries: [
    {
      message: "this is a message #1",
      postedTime: new Date(),
      author: "coffeemeup"
    }]
});
```

I'm trying to insert another document into the **entries** array using the code below. But not only does that not work, it throws a "*Mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly...*" error. I'd really appreciate some help!

```
Conversations.update({
    channel: "#defaultChannel"
}, {
    $push: {
        entries: {
            message: newMessage,
            postedTime: new Date(),
            author: "coffeemeup"
        }
    }
});
```

Also, I would love to hear suggestions on how to better structure/design this database to build a Slack clone.

Comment: you should use `$set` instead of `$push`

Comment: I think that he does want to use `$push`

Comment: Maybe try [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)

Comment: is the var newMessage defined previously as a string?  I think this error is complaining that the values that are being insert are of a different type than what is already in the collection.  For instance, if you first "message" was a string and you second message was an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run update operations on clients, you need to use the `_id` field. Otherwise you will get this error:

> Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID.
>   [403]

As a result, get the document first and subsequently use the document's `_id` to run the update query.

For example:

```
var conversation = Conversations.findOne({
    "channel": "#defaultChannel"
});

Conversations.update({
    _id: conversation._id
}, {
    $push: {
        entries: {
            message: "newMessage",
            postedTime: new Date(),
            author: "coffeemeup"
        }
    }
});
```

Here is what the updated conversation document looks like:

```
{
   "_id": "wGixGJgoM6fk57mtN",
   "channel": "#defaultChannel",
   "createdBy": "coffeemeup",
   "timestamp": "2015-07-27T19:25:52.842Z",
   "followers": [
      "username1",
      "username2"
   ],
   "entries": [
      {
         "message": "this is a message #1",
         "postedTime": "2015-07-27T19:25:52.842Z",
         "author": "coffeemeup"
      },
      {
         "message": "newMessage",
         "postedTime": "2015-07-27T19:27:54.930Z",
         "author": "coffeemeup"
      }
   ]
}
```